# Using dns.lookup in node.js to test proxy connectivity

Tags: node.js, proxy, dns, http-proxy, connectivity

I've been using dns module in node.js to test current network connectivity by attempting to resolve a fixed host name (e.g. google.com) at regular intervals using dns.lookup:

```
var dns = require('dns');
dns.lookup('google.com',function(err) {
    console.log((err && err.code == "ENOTFOUND") ? 'No available connection' : 'Connection is available');
});
```

Which works well and can be run on a loop to inform if the network has dropped. What I now need to be able to do is check if the connection via a proxy server is available (the setup will have http requests from a local machine forwarded to an http proxy server on a tethered mobile device, in order to use the mobile network - the local machine will need to monitor the connectivity of the mobile network).

Ideally I'd like to use the same method above with a proxy configuration, but I'm not sure if this can be achieved with dns.lookup

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to test an HTTP proxy server, you will need to send HTTP requests, not DNS requests.

If you want an easy and quick solution, you can use a utility library like [is-online](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-online):

```
const isOnline = require('is-online');
(async () => {
    console.log(await isOnline());
    //=> true
})();
```

It tests for both DNS and HTTP, and I have good personal experience with it. You will need to configure the proxy (See instructions in the link).

Comment: I'd still need to test that the host is reachable via the proxy server - is it possible to configure proxy settings when using this library? Otherwise it looks like the solution will have to be period HEAD requests using a node http client

Comment: You are correct - so I edited my answer and replaced is-reachable with is-online, which can be configured to use a proxy. Of course, using standard node.js HTTP client with proxy and implementing the test logic yourself is also an option,